# Scala function return different results when applied in an UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a function which return an insertion point in a "search right" manner:

```
import scala.collection.Searching._

def getPit(samples: Seq[Int], obs: Int) : Int = { 
    val pitValue = samples.map(-_).reverse.search(-obs) match {
        case Found(i)          => sampless.length - i
        case InsertionPoint(i) => sampless.length - i
        } // looking for the insertion in a "search right" manner
    pitValue
}
```

So for these examples I get the following results :

```
println(getPit(Seq(1, 1, 2, 2), 0)) # 0
println(getPit(Seq(2, 2, 2, 5), 0)) # 0
println(getPit(Seq(0, 1, 7, 10), 7)) # 3
println(getPit(Seq(0, 4, 5, 6), 7)) # 4
println(getPit(Seq(0, 1, 2, 2), 2)) # 4
println(getPit(Seq(1, 1, 1, 1), 1)) # 4
println(getPit(Seq(0, 1, 2, 2), 4)) # 4
```

Which is exactly what I want.

**Now applying this function in a UDF** like this:

```
val pitValuesUDF = udf { (samples: Seq[Int], obs: Int) =>
  getPit(samples, obs)
}

val   df =  Seq( ("a",0, Seq(1, 1, 2,2)),
    ("b", 0, Seq(2, 2, 2, 5)),
    ("b", 7, Seq(0, 1, 7, 10)),
    ("b", 7, Seq(0, 4, 5, 6)),
    ("b", 2, Seq(0, 1, 2, 2)),
    ("a", 1, Seq(1, 1, 1, 1)),
    ("b", 4, Seq(0, 1, 2, 2))
 ).toDF("sku_id", "sale_qty", "samples")

df.withColumn("pit", pitValuesUDF(col("samples"), col("sale_qty"))).show
```

I got different results:

```
+------+--------+-------------+---+
|sku_id|sale_qty|      samples|pit|
+------+--------+-------------+---+
|     a|       0| [1, 1, 2, 2]|  0|
|     b|       0| [2, 2, 2, 5]|  0|
|     b|       7|[0, 1, 7, 10]|  3|
|     b|       7| [0, 4, 5, 6]|  4|
|     b|       2| [0, 1, 2, 2]|  3|
|     a|       1| [1, 1, 1, 1]|  3|
|     b|       4| [0, 1, 2, 2]|  4|
+------+--------+-------------+---+
```

Do you have any idea why the results are different between the 2 cases? And how can I make the UDF to return the value in the first case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok I got the answer.** Looking at the scala implementation of search [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.6/src/library/scala/collection/Searching.scala#L1).
We can see that there is a case:

```
 final def search[B >: A](elem: B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): SearchResult =
      coll match {
        case _: IndexedSeqLike[A, Repr] => binarySearch(elem, 0, coll.length)(ord)
        case _ => linearSearch(coll.view, elem, 0)(ord)
      }
```

And guess what **binarySearch and linearSearch will not return the same index** when there are duplicates in the collection. This explain why there might be different results for different collection types.

To be more concrete in the first case the Seq type is not an IndexedSeqLike so this is a linear which is performed (and that what I want). Whereas in the udf by checking the `samples.getClass` I noticed that it in fact a WrappedArray which is child of IndexedSeqLike so a binarySearch is perform (and it is not what I want).

Knowing that I just have to **cast everything to List** to make sure it is a linear search which will be applied under the hood.